# Why was Jeremiah named in Matthew 16:14?

Tags: matthew

Matthew 16:

> 13 When Jesus came to the region of Caesarea Philippi, he asked his disciples, “Who do people say the **Son of Man** is?”
>
> 14 They replied, “Some say John the Baptist; others say Elijah; and still others, **Jeremiah** or one of the prophets.”

Why was Jeremiah mentioned here at all? Is there OT justification for connecting the Son of Man with Jeremiah?

Answer (score 1):

As in the Moses' times (in **Deuteronomy 18:15**), we see in the law:

> 15 The LORD thy God will raise up unto thee a Prophet from the midst
> of thee, of thy brethren, like unto me; unto him ye shall hearken; (KJV)

That's why, Jeremiah meaning the one G'd will appoint, is believed to come, as a leader such as Moses.

The cabal proof is given in Baal Hatturim in Deut. xviii. 15. R. Abraham Seba; **Tzeror Hammor**, fol. 127. 4. & 143. 4, this commentary compares the way of Jeremiah and that of Moses:

*R. Judah, the son of R. Simon, opened ( Deuteronomy 18:18 ) ( 34:10 ) thus: "as thee", this is **Jeremiah**, who was, as he, in reproofs; you will find **all that is written of the one, is written of the other**; **one prophesied forty years**, and **the other prophesied forty years**; the one prophesied concerning **Judah and Israel**, and the other prophesied concerning **Judah and Israel**; against the one those of **his own tribe stood up**, and against **the other those of his own tribe stood up**; **the one was cast into a river**, **and the other into a dungeon**; the one was **delivered by means of an handmaid**, and **the other by the means of a servant**; the one came with words of reproof, and the other came with words of reproof.*

However, it's very clear that when Matthew wrote what he did, to me he uses **mystical concepts** (*caballistic ones*), because Jeremiah is dead, so how can he call him to come again? He is talking about **archetypes**, i.e., types that represent characteristics of **hebrew language** and in some way, there is naturally a connection with people in the Torah (pentateuch), this happens, because it's first, not a story of people, but of the **spiritual levels** described by **hebrew grammar**.

The same thing happens with John the Baptist, for wasn't he that was Jesus's cousin that came before him (**Malachi 4:5**), but he was actually Elias'(which means He (Adonai) is my G'd, the same as Eliahu,) archetype, (**Luke 1:17**).

Comment: I have to wonder if the NASB doesn't provide a more correct understanding: **Matthew 16:14**: "And they said, 'Some say John the Baptist; and others, Elijah; and still others, Jeremiah, or one of the *other* prophets.'" If this is the case, Jeremiah is simply being used as one of the many prophets.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of ancient prophets reappearing was, in part at least, based on two famous passages:

- Deut 18:15, 18 - The LORD your God will raise up for you a prophet like me from among your brothers. You must listen to him. ... I will raise up for them a prophet like you from among their brothers. I will put My words in his mouth, and he will tell them everything I command him.
- Mal 4:5 - Behold, I will send you Elijah the prophet before the coming of the great and awesome Day of the LORD.

In the dialogue recorded in Matt 16:14, two prophets are mentioned:

- **Elijah** - presumably a reference to Mal 4:5, who, as far as we know, did not contribute to the OT can of Scripture
- **Jeremiah** - a prophet who did contribute to the OT canon of Scripture

However, in the parallel accounts of Mark 8:28 and Luke 9:19, Jeremiah is not mentioned, only, "one of the other prophets".

Ellicott has some useful background here in his comments on Matt 16:14:

> The passage is of the greatest possible interest as one of the very
> few that indicate the impressions shaped into beliefs that were
> floating among the people as to our Lord’s character and mission. They
> were based, it will be seen in each case, upon a popular doctrine of
> transmigration, to which the Pharisees had given a place in their
> system of teaching. The great actors of the past were still in
> existence. They might, at any great national crisis, reappear to
> continue and complete their work. Each of the answers has a further
> special interest of its own.
>
> **(1.)** The identification of our Lord with the Baptist has already met us as coming from the lips of the tetrarch Antipas, adopted, but
> not originated, by him as explaining our Lord’s mighty works (Matthew
> 14:2; Luke 9:7).
>
> **(2.)** The belief that Elijah had reappeared was of the same nature. He was expected as the forerunner of the Messiah (Malachi 4:5). The
> imagination of the people had at first seen in the Baptist the
> reappearance of the Tishbite, but he, though working in the spirit and
> power of Elijah, had disclaimed the character which was thus ascribed
> to him, and it was natural that the imagination of the people should
> now turn to One who appeared to them as simply continuing his work.
> The character of our Lord’s recent miracles, corresponding as it did
> to that which was recorded as wrought by Elijah for the widow of
> Sarepta (1 Kings 17:14), had probably strengthened that impression.
>
> **(3.)** The name of Jeremiah introduces a new train of legendary thought. The impression made by that prophet on the minds of men had
> led to something like a mythical after-growth. It was said that the
> spirit of Jeremiah had passed into Zechariah (see Note on Matthew
> 27:9), and on that assumption another reappearance might well seem
> probable. He, it was believed, had hidden the ark, and the tabernacle,
> and the altar of incense in a cave in “the mountain where Moses
> climbed up and saw the heritage of God”—i.e., in Nebo, or Pisgah (2
> Maccabees 2:1-7)—and was expected to come and guide the people in the
> time “when God should gather His people together” to the place of
> concealment. He had appeared to Judas Maccabeus in a vision as “a man
> with grey hairs, and exceeding glorious,” and as the guardian prophet
> of the people, praying for them and for the Holy City, had given him a
> golden sword as the gift of God (2 Maccabees 15:13-16). As the prophet
> who had foretold the new covenant and the coming of the Lord our
> Righteousness (Jeremiah 23:6; Jeremiah 31:31) he was identified, as
> thoroughly as Isaiah, with the Messianic expectations of the people.
> Something, we may add, there may have been in our Lord’s human aspect,
> as a Man of sorrows and acquainted with grief, which may have helped
> to suggest this identification with the prophet who was, above all
> others of the goodly company, a prophet of lamentations and tears and
> woe.
>
> **(4.)** The last conjecture was more vague and undefined, and was probably the resource of those who were impressed with wonder at our
> Lord’s words and works, and yet could not bring themselves to
> acknowledge Him as what He claimed to be. All the four conjectures, it
> will be seen, fell far short of the recognition of the Christ.

Thus, it appears that the specific mention of Jeremiah was simply used as an exemplar or arch-type of one the many other ancient prophets.